# Confused about the header size for a Ethernet frame

Tags: header, frame, lan, ethernet

I was researching a few things about `VLANs` and came across the `VLAN tag` and also the headers.

If we have a MTU for a standard `802.3 Ethernet frame` (1518 bytes) what is included in the header `802.3`?

Also how do we calculate the header length for that?

What is the difference between `802.3 and 802.1q`? I know that the VLAN tag requires extra bytes but how to calculate how many bytes needed to the `802.1q VLAN tag`?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A regular 802.3/Eth-II ethernet frame doesn't carry VLAN info.
802.1Q can carry VLAN (and QoS) info over to the receiving end.

If the ethertype is 0x8100 then you got yourself an 802.1Q tag which is another 4 bytes in addition to the 14 bytes (dmac+smac+type).

See wikipedia for reference. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame

**EDIT:**

Regular Eth-II/802.3 has a total length of:

dmac(6)+smac(6)+etype(2)+payload(1500)+crc(4) = 1518 bytes

For the case of Eth-II/802.3 with 802.1Q tagging:

dmac(6)+smac(6)+8100(2)+vlan/Qos(2)+etype(2)+payload(1500)+crc(4) = 1522 bytes

Comment: so what will be the total length for 802.3?